# Can't update Skype, please help?

Tags: package-management, skype, debian

```
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 166465 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace skype 2.2.0.35-0precise3 (using .../skype-debian_4.0.0.8-1_i386 (1).deb) ...
Unpacking replacement skype ...
dpkg: error processing /home/ybnrmalatall/Downloads/skype-debian_4.0.0.8-1_i386 (1).deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/skype', which is also in package skype-bin 2.2.0.35-0precise3
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal gzip write error: Broken pipe
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb (subprocess): failed in write on buffer copy for failed to write to pipe in copy: Broken pipe
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/ybnrmalatall/Downloads/skype-debian_4.0.0.8-1_i386 (1).deb
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove skype skype-bin`,`sudo dpkg -i '/home/ybnrmalatall/Downloads/skype-debian_4.0.0.8-1_i386 (1).deb'`

Answer (score 2):

From what it looks like, you are trying to install skype 4.0 from the .deb on their website, while you have skype 2.whatever installed. You must `sudo apt-get purge skype` before you try to install skype 4.0; I had a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

First remove existing skype  and install gdebi package manager, Then right click on the downloaded skype deb and open with gdebi package manager, press install button . Enjoy